# Javascript function is deactivated by default

Tags: javascript, import

I have created an export class called request.js.
I imported this class into my script.js and created a new instance of the object.

The following function after den new instance is then deactivated by default. I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadLocation is not defined.

```
import Request from './request.js';
let request = new Request();

function LoadLocation() { // << why deactivated by default?

    let LocationTable = document.getElementById('LocationTable');
    LocationTable.innerHTML = '';

    // Method from request.js
    request.execute({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/location/',
        datatype: 'json',

        successCallback: function (response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Get the Location Data');

                for (let location in response) {

                    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    let tdName = document.createElement('td');
                    let tdStreet = document.createElement('td');
                    let tdPostcode = document.createElement('td');
                    let tdPlace = document.createElement('td');

                    tr.appendChild(tdName);
                    tr.appendChild(tdStreet);
                    tr.appendChild(tdPostcode);
                    tr.appendChild(tdPlace);

                    tdName.innerHTML = location.location_name;
                    tdStreet.innerHTML = location.street;
                    tdPostcode.innerHTML = location.postcode;
                    tdPlace.innerHTML = location.place;

                    LocationTable.appendChild(tr);
                }
            } else document.getElementById('divMsg').innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-danger">Daten von Ausgabestellen konnten nicht geladen werden!</div>`;
        },

        errorCallback: function (s, t) {
            console.log('Error: LoadLocation!!!');
            console.error(s + ': ' + t);
        }
    });
}
```

However, the function is integrated in my html with:

```
...
<script>
LoadLocation();
</script>
</body>
```

i am relatively new to javascript. can someone give me a tip on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is not deactivated, it is simply not visible. The `LoadLocation()` call in you `script` tag requires/expects a function `LoadLocation` on the global `window` object and it can't find it there.

A quick solution: add this to your script:

```
window.LoadLocation = LoadLocation;
```

Edit:

When the browser renders the html, it 'executes' it from top to bottom. For scripts, that means that your own script, which defines the `LoadLocation` function and assigns it to the `window` object must appear on the HTML *before* you use the function in the script tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. i added that to the script (right before the import statement. the function became visible (at least for the editor) and when executing the same error occurred :/

Comment: @Tobias I guess, you load your script near the end of the HTML file, at least after you use it. The parse execute each `script` as soon as it finds it on the html file. Make sure that the function has been defined and assigned to `window` *before* you execute it.